# How can I change direction of the text in Word?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word

I have a project where I would like to change direction of the text in MS Word format. In my project I used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, What are your experiences?

Comment: My experiences are very good. And how are yours?

Comment: My friend, I want an instruction like this to change the direction of the text, thank you
oPara3.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

Answer (score 0):

```
Word.Application w= new Word.Application();
object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Paragraph wp= w.Paragraphs.Add(ref objMissing);
wp.ReadingOrder = WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `Orientation`of a text or actually a `Range` that you can change it like this:

```
document.Words.Last.Orientation = Word.WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationDownward;
```

or for a cell of a table:

```
table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Orientation = Word.WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationUpward;
```

`Word.WdTextOrientation` enum has below values:

```
wdTextOrientationDownward
wdTextOrientationHorizontal
WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationHorizontalRotatedFarEast
WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationUpward
WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationVertical
WdTextOrientation.wdTextOrientationVerticalFarEast
```